# Cassandra ERROR Stop listening to thrift clients during repair

Tags: cassandra

I have an AWS EC2 Cassandra 1.2.8 cluster running on 6 m1.large instances with jna.jar available. I am doing some testing with disaster recovery where I download snapshots of my data from s3 and install it on a new cluster. Then I try to run nodetool repair on a node. After some period of time (could be an hour or so) I periodically get the message

```
failed with error java.io.IOException: Cannot proceed on repair because a neighbor (/10.0.22.162) is dead: session failed
```

When I log into 10.0.22.162 I see that the CassandraDaemon java process is still running but `netstat -ant` indicates that the instance is no longer listening to port 9160.

Looking at the cassandra logs the last thing I see the following:

```
INFO [AntiEntropyStage:1] 2013-08-20 16:08:53,340 AntiEntropyService.java (line 245) [repair #cdb7f2a0-09b2-11e3-bc42-4bd65b6bc771] Sending completed merkle tree to /10.0.32.59 for (dummy,foo)
ERROR [Thread-1657] 2013-08-20 16:08:53,828 FileUtils.java (line 381) Stopping RPC server
INFO [Thread-1657] 2013-08-20 16:08:53,828 ThriftServer.java (line 116) Stop listening to thrift clients
ERROR [Thread-1657] 2013-08-20 16:08:53,830 FileUtils.java (line 387) Stopping native transport
INFO [Thread-1657] 2013-08-20 16:08:53,838 Server.java (line 151) Stop listening for CQL clients
```

Does anyone have any idea where/how I might track this down and figure out why the thrift server goes on an extended vacation?

I know nodetool repair is a pig of a process so if someone tells me that it is resource-bound I might need a little more information on how to track that down.

Comment: what's in the /var/log/syslog ?